# How do I sample few numbers with different distributions?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy

Let say I have my own custom distribution numpy vector called `p`.

Then `p` satisfies the following:

```
np.ndim(p) == 1 & np.sum(p) == 1 & np.all(p >= 0)
```

With that vector I can easily sample a number in `[0, p.shape)` with `np.random.choice(np.arange(len(p)), p=p)`

In a case I have many such `p`s, I have a matrix (with dim 2) `P` that satisfies:

```
np.sum(P[:,i]) == 1   # for all i in P.shape[1]
np.all(P >= 0)
```

Then I wish to sample `P.shape[1]` numbers in the range 0 to `P.shape[0]` with probability P.

For example the next code:

```
P = np.array([[0.2, 0.3],
              [0.5, 0.7],
              [0.3, 0]])
x = np.random.choice(np.arange(P.shape[0], P[:,0]))
y = np.random.choice(np.arange(P.shape[0], P[:,1]))
```

will produce my will (`x=0` in `0.2`, `x=1` in `0.5` and `x=2` in `0.3` and `y=0` in `0.3`, `y=1` in `0.7`).

In my case `P` has many columns and I wish to sample all in one shot.

Of course I can do it in a for loop,  for example:

```
random_values = np.empty(P.shape[1])
arange_arr = np.arange(P.shape[0])
for i in range(P.shape[1]):
    random_values[i] = np.random.choice(arange_arr, p=P[:,i])
```

Trying to find some nupmy-scipy elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
P = np.array([[0.2, 0.3],
              [0.5, 0.7],
              [0.3, 0]])
P_upper = np.cumsum(P, axis=0)
P_lower = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1, P.shape[1])), P_upper[:-1, :]), axis=0)
```

This creates a set of bins that you can digitize into. Now generate random numbers between 0 and 1:

```
r = np.random.rand(10, P.shape[1])
```

There are a couple of ways to assign the data to the right bins. The quick and relatively inefficient way is to use a boolean mask:

```
mask = (r[None, ...] >= P_lower[:, None, :]) & (r[None, ...] < P_upper[:, None, :])
result = np.argmax(mask, axis=0)
```

A more efficient, but more complicated, way is to add an offset to each column, and apply `np.digitize` or `np.searchsorted` to the result:

```
offset = np.arange(P.shape[1])
ind = np.searchsorted((P_upper + offset).ravel('F'), (r + offset).ravel('F')).reshape(r.shape, order='F')
result = ind - offset * P.shape[0]
```

**TL;DR**

```
def multi_sample(p, n):
    ps = np.cumsum(p, axis=0)
    r = np.random.rand(n, ps.shape[1])
    offset = np.arange(P.shape[1])
    ind = np.searchsorted((P_upper + offset).ravel('F'), (r + offset).ravel('F')).reshape(r.shape, order='F')
    return ind - offset * P.shape[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, I hoped for some built-in function in mupy/scipy.. =\

Comment: @Shaq. You can make your own utility function. This should not be an issue. I'll add a TL;DR

Comment: thanks. I think TL;DR might be better in the start of the answer, doesn't it?